# Android Spinner get selected item

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have created 2 spinner in an same activity,

for example

1. Country
2. State

Whenever, if Country is selected it will display some countries like Japan,China, etc...

If i select China in another spinner like state which diaplays only china states and city or if i select japan in another spinner it display only japan states

[image]

Comment: What you tried so far ??

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Show your code. What have you tried till now.

Comment: From where you fill up Array in to Spinner of Country if you will add  json in to CountrySpinner than you also getting the country_id

Comment: You can use a flag for every country you are selecting. And using that flag variable, check if(flag == YOUR_COUNTRY), then show cities(array) in the City spinner.

Comment: Thanks Akhil Nair

Answer (score 3):

You can get currently selected item by

```
String currentSelectedItem = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

OR

mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing in my project :

If you use are getting Country array from JSON than Just follow the step as bellow :

> Note: Make sure you also get **country_id** and **state_id** to pass
>   country id to state request parameter for same what you want

**step 1:** First you should fill all countries in to array and set country adapter

**step 2:** than  `spinnerCountry.setAdapter()` on `onCreate()` hop you understood

**step 3:** after than  `spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener()` you are getting the country_id using position of selected spinner item, pass that country_id to state request parameter for getting state response

**step 4:** Thats all you get state response and set adater  `spinnerState.setAdapter()` with your response state array

Answer (score 0):

I've finaly added the code for muliple spinner in same activity.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

```
Spinner Cou, Sta, Cit;
Button button;
String name[]={"India","SriLanka"};
String flag1="India";
String flag2="SriLanka";
String flag3="Western Province";
String flag4="Central Province";
String flag5="Southern Province";
String name1[]={"Tamilnadu","kerala","karnataka"};
String name2[]={"Western","Central","Southern"};
String name3[]={"Colombo","Gampaha","Kalutara"};
String name4[]={"Kandy","Nuwara-Eliya","Matale"};
String name5[]={"Galle","Matara","Hambantota"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Cou = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name);
    Cou.setAdapter( arrayAdapter);
    Cou.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Sta = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter aadapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name1);
    Sta.setAdapter(aadapter);
    Sta.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Cit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter barrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name2);
    Cit.setAdapter(barrayAdapter);
    Cit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Cit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter carrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name3);
    Cit.setAdapter(carrayAdapter);
    Cit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Cit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter darrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name4);
    Cit.setAdapter(darrayAdapter);
    Cit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Cit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter earrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name5);
    Cit.setAdapter(earrayAdapter);
    Cit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", String.valueOf(Cou.getSelectedItem()));
            intent.putExtra("datam", String.valueOf(Sta.getSelectedItem()));
            intent.putExtra("datama", String.valueOf(Cit.getSelectedItem()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome" + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

    if(item=="India"){
        Sta = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter aadapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name1);
        Sta.setAdapter(aadapter);
        Sta.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    } else if(item=="SriLanka"){
        Sta = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter aadapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name2);
        Sta.setAdapter(aadapter);
        Sta.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    } else if(item=="Western"){
        Cit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter carrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name3);
        Cit.setAdapter(carrayAdapter);
        Cit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    } else if(item=="Central"){
        Cit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter darrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name4);
        Cit.setAdapter(darrayAdapter);
        Cit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }else if(item=="Southern"){
        Cit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter earrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,name5);
        Cit.setAdapter(earrayAdapter);
        Cit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

}